# I want to get latest record from SQL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Before this process I tried displaying only users table using this code and it works great.

```
$this->db->join('tablename', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'right outer');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblanswers ORDER BY answerid DESC LIMIT 1")->row();
```

More about this you can find here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: It works fine but its better to use DB functions. like order_by() and limit()

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db
     ->join('tablename', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'right outer')
     ->order_by('title', 'DESC');
```